# Using $.getJSON in .NET MVC 3.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

I want to use jQuery.getJSON function in ASP.NET MVC 3.0, so I wrote the code below for test:

```
    <input id="btn" type="button" />

<script>
        $("#btn").click(function () {
            $.getJSON("/Location/GetData", null, function (data) {
                alert(data);
            });
        });


</script>
```

and I have a LocationController with below method:

```
public JsonResult GetData()
        {
            List<int> result = new List<int>(){1, 4, 5};
            return Json(result);
        }
```

But it doesn't work!
The GetData method calls, but 'alert' is not shown!

Comment: you should use firebug and turn on the net tab and check the xhr. it should tell u what the post and response of your ajax calls are.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to tell MVC to allow your JSON action to be called via GETs by changing your return to:

```
return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

By default ([for security reasons](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/06/25/json-hijacking.aspx)) they only allow Json to be requested via POSTs.

Comment: While that does allow a person to get passed the issue, it isn't a good solution due to the security issue you mentioned. The better answer is http://stackoverflow.com/a/6196969/39532

Comment: @mezoid - There's nothing inherently wrong with using JSON in conjunction with GETs so long as you're not using to pass sensitive information (or to perform actions). Lots of libraries allow/support it (jQuery has `getJSON`, google maps API support JSON GETs, etc, etc). As with many things in development, it basically boils down to being aware of the security issues (as linked to in my answer) and using the right tools for the job.

Comment: I agree with what you're saying. however, it is not clear whether the op has sensitive data in his real-world usecase. I can imagine that the op and anyone else who benefits from your reply may take the answer for granted and not dig to fully understand the security concern. I would think that your answer would be better if you broke it into two sections. 1 If you have sensitive data do this... 2 If you know your data is not sensitive you can do this...

Answer (score 5):

To protect against [cross-side-scripting attacks & JSON Hijacking](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/06/25/json-hijacking.aspx), MVC 2+ (I think it was 2), requires that you access actions with JSON responses using `POST`, rather than `GET`.

You can override this behaviour by using the overload of `Json()`, where you set the `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` flag, but as described in the blog post, this is not a good/safe idea.

The way I do all of my JSON requests, whether they be jsut loading data, or posting back, is to use the [`$.post`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) jQuery method, and limit the controller action to only accept `HttpPost`.

so your code would become:

```
$("#btn").click(function () {
    $.post("/Location/GetData", null, function (data) {
        alert(data);
    });
});
```

and

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetData()
{
    List<int> result = new List<int>(){1, 4, 5};
    return Json(result);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all. Install Firebug for Firefox so you can inspect the response the server sends, Chrome and IE has built in tools you can use too.

Without knowing the response I will assume the problem is that ASP.NET MVC protects you against JSON hijacking byt not allowing to return JSON for a GET request by default.

Try changing to:

```
return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```